# How can I find all downvoted and all unanswered questions?

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions

I want to see all downvoted questions in one section and only unanswered questions in one section.

Is there any way to accomplish this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Your title and your question say 2 slightly different things.  Are you looking for **your** downvoted and unanswered, or all downvoted, and all unanswered?

Comment: all down and all un answered.....

Comment: I've edited your question to what I think you are asking based on your comment.  Feel free to rollback if you don't think the edited question reflects what you are asking.

Comment: you are fantastic, thanks boss......

Comment: why down vote for this question too..?..... seems pepoles want to downvote too much....

Comment: Do you mean all questions that have received at least one downvote (but may still have a positive score because they got more upvotes than downvotes), or all questions that have a negative score?

Comment: if there are chances , i want to know both @Louis

Comment: @BabyinCoding maybe understanding what you are actually looking for would help understand your question.  what do you actually want to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why anyone would want this query, but it's not hard to do in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.  Keep in mind that it's not up-to-the-minute data, so questions may have been upvoted or deleted in the interim.

[Link to query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/429987/unanswered-and-downvoted-questions)

```
SELECT ID [Post Link], Score, CreationDate
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1
AND Score < 0
AND AnswerCount = 0
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC;
```

The hunt for slightly more advanced information I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 6):

Just use search, there are [lots of useful operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) you can use:

> answers:0 score:..0

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20score%3a..0